# javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path Error Occures

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jax-rs

I found this same question in here few times, but I couldn't find an answer to that.

When I run my application, Im getting the following error

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/RemoteQuartzScheduler/rest/TestClass/hello
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is the pom file of the project (I only added the main parts)

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here is my **web.xml** file

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<display-name>RemoteQuartzScheduler</display-name>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Here is my **Test.java** class

```
@Path("/TestClass")
public class Test implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -262701666015379272L;

  @GET
  @Path("/hello")
  public Response heloMessage() {

    String result = "Hello Word!!!!!!!!!";

    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
  }   
}
```

**Please tell me where did I do wrong?? Thanks in advance**

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: @Jens added the complete stack trace

Comment: Is `RemoteQuartzScheduler` the name of your `ear` file?

Comment: yes, its the name of my war file

Comment: and if I jut enter http://localhost:8080/RemoteQuartzScheduler/, it will show Hello World! . not Hello Word!!!!!!!!! which I used in my Test class

Comment: Without any version numbers? Any Excpetions in logfile at startup/ deployment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70992/discussion-between-ravindu-and-jens).

Comment: Try and add the context  param `resteasy.scan` to `true`. See [Configuration Switches](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#d4e125)

Comment: @peeskillet still the same,
I added  <context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: Try this. Comment out the whole web.xml, and create an `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` subclass in the project. Just leave it empty. Annotate it with `@ApplicationPath("/rest")`. This should for the most part work. Just trying to see if it is something else.

Comment: @peeskillet then it gives a 404 error (The requested resource is not available.)

Comment: What Tomcat version are you using?

Comment: oH.... I'M REALLY SORRY SIR, IT WORKS. Instead of a subclass I created a class named application

Comment: @peeskillet can u please explain what did u do there? now my web.xml file is completely empty. If u can, please give it as a answer so others also can see it. Thank you

Comment: I am facing same issue. I created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285602/jaxrs-could-not-find-resource-for-full-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't gotten a chance to test your version (with the web.xml), and honestly I don't work much with xml when I *do* use Resteasy, so I won't go trying to explain what is wrong (if anything) with the web.xml.

But when working with an `javax.xs.rs.core.Application` subclass, we can define an `@ApplicationPath("/path")` annotation. This defines a servlet for our JAX-RS application, with the url mapping of `/path/*`. This is specified in the JAX-RS spec.

You can see more here about this deployment option, as well as others, in section [2.3.2 Configuration - Servlet](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html). This is a 1.1 spec (you are using 2.0), but the deployment options are similar. I just couldn't find an html link to the 2.0. You can download the pdf though from [here](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html).

You can also read more about deployments with Resteasy [here in the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#d4e111).

But basically, what this deployment option does is scan for annotations of `@Path`, `@Provider`, etc for the application. The reason is that JAX-RS will first look for classes and object in overridden `getClasses()` and `getSingletons()`, respectively. If then return empty sets, this tell JAX-RS to do scanning (per the spec).